# Python 3 - Pandas, DataFrame, ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I see others are having issues with this as well, but I haven't found a working solution from other posts yet, and maybe because I'm not implementing it properly yet. I'm making a scraper for a job posting website and this is the section of code I'm working/having trouble with:

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time



# URL of specific job search
# FUTURE TO DO - Break it up into editable variables based on URL structure
URL = 'https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=data+scientist,+data+analyst,+python&l=Canada&jt=fulltime'
# conducting a request of the stated URL above:
page = requests.get(URL)
# specifying a desired format of “page” using the html parser - this allows python to read the various components of the page, rather than treating it as one long string.
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
# printing soup in a more structured tree format that makes for easier reading
# print(soup.prettify())



# Extract job title
def extract_job_title_from_result(soup): 
    jobs = []
    for div in soup.findAll(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
        for a in div.findAll(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
            jobs.append(a['title'])
    return(jobs)
extract_job_title_from_result(soup)



# Extract company
def extract_company_from_result(soup): 
    companies = []
    for div in soup.findAll(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
        company = div.findAll(name='span', attrs={'class':'company'})
        if len(company) > 0:
            for b in company:
                companies.append(b.text.strip())
        else:
            sec_try = div.findAll(name='span', attrs={'class':'result-link-source'})
            for span in sec_try:
                companies.append(span.text.strip())
    return(companies)
extract_company_from_result(soup)



# Extract location
def extract_location_from_result(soup): 
    locations = []
    spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'location'})
    for span in spans:
        locations.append(span.text)
    return(locations)
extract_location_from_result(soup)



# Extract salary
def extract_salary_from_result(soup): 
    salaries = []
    for div in soup.findAll(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
        try:
          salaries.append(div.find('nobr').text)
        except:
            try:
                div_two = div.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'sjcl'})
                div_three = div_two.find('div')
                salaries.append(div_three.text.strip())
            except:
                salaries.append('Nothing_found')
    return(salaries)
extract_salary_from_result(soup)



# Extract job summary
# FUTURE TO DO - Extract full job description by each job page posting 
# ie. going through the link
def extract_summary_from_result(soup): 
    summaries = []
    spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'summary'})
    for span in spans:
        summaries.append(span.text.strip())
    return(summaries)
extract_summary_from_result(soup)



# Max results per city, which cities, and an output for the data
max_results_per_city = 10
city_set = ['Canada'] # 'New+York','Chicago','San+Francisco', 'Austin', 'Seattle', 'Los+Angeles', 'Philadelphia', 'Atlanta', 'Dallas', 'Pittsburgh', 'Portland', 'Phoenix', 'Denver', 'Houston', 'Miami', 'Washington+DC', 'Boulder']
columns = ['city', 'job_title', 'company_name', 'location', 'summary', 'salary']
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)



#scraping code:
for city in city_set:
    for start in range(0, max_results_per_city, 10):
        page = requests.get('http://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=data+scientist,+data+analyst,+python&l=' + str(city) + '&jt=fulltime')  # + '&start=' + str(start))
        time.sleep(1)  #ensuring at least 1 second between page grabs

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        for div in soup.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
    #creating an empty list to hold the data for each posting
            job_post = []
    #append city name
            job_post.append(city)
    #grabbing job title
            for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
                job_post.append(a['title']) 
    #grabbing company name
                company = div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'company'}) 
                if len(company) > 0:
                    [job_post.append(b.text.strip()) for b in company]
                else:
                    [job_post.append(span.text) for span in div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'result-link-source'})]
    #grabbing location name
                [job_post.append(span.text) for span in div.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'location'})]
    #grabbing summary text
                [job_post.append(span.text.strip()) for span in div.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'summary'})]
    #grabbing salary
                div_two = div.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'salarySnippet'})
                job_post.append(div_two.text.strip() if div_two else 'Nothing found')
    #appending list of job post info to dataframe at index num
                sample_df.loc[len(sample_df) + 1] = job_post

#saving sample_df as a local csv file — define your own local path to save contents 
sample_df.to_csv('[filepath].csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

I seem to be having issues with the second line, or the very last line. Receiving the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 128, in <module>
    sample_df.loc[len(sample_df) + 1] = job_post
  File "C:\Users\...Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 194, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 439, in _setitem_with_indexer
    raise ValueError("cannot set a row with "
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

I saw a few solutions of using .append instead of .DataFrame, however I receive an error that Pandas doesn't use .append, or something along those lines. Any suggestions?

This was an older code from last year that I'm taking from:

https://medium.com/@msalmon00/web-scraping-job-postings-from-indeed-96bd588dcb4b

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include all the imports in your code too (so that it is easy for others who try it out )

Comment: @SruthiV Thanks, I've updated to show my full code, and the full error message I'm receiving. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't get the main solution to work, but I did a workaround just using a .writerow and it works just as fine. I'll play with the dataframe thing later. Thanks everyone!

```
#scraping code:
with open('output.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output) #delimiter=",")
    for city in city_set:
        for start in range(0, max_results_per_city, 10):
            page = requests.get('http://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=data+scientist,+data+analyst,+python&l=' + str(city) + '&jt=fulltime')  # + '&start=' + str(start))
            time.sleep(1)  #ensuring at least 1 second between page grabs

            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
            for div in soup.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
    #creating an empty list to hold the data for each posting
                job_post = []
    #append city name
                job_post.append(city)
    #grabbing job title
                for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
                    job_post.append(a['title']) 
    #grabbing company name
                    company = div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'company'}) 
                    if len(company) > 0:
                        [job_post.append(b.text.strip()) for b in company]
                    else:
                        [job_post.append(span.text) for span in div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'result-link-source'})]
    #grabbing location name
                    [job_post.append(span.text) for span in div.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'location'})]
    #grabbing summary text
                    [job_post.append(span.text.strip()) for span in div.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'summary'})]
    #grabbing salary
                    div_two = div.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'salarySnippet'})
                    job_post.append(div_two.text.strip() if div_two else 'Nothing found')
    #appending list of job post info to dataframe at index num
                    #sample_df.loc[len(sample_df) + 1] = job_post

#saving sample_df as a local csv file — define your own local path to save contents 
                csv_output.writerow([job_post])
                #sample_df.to_csv('[filepath].csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error. I added the dependencies (`pandas` and `time`) and made some assumptions about the unspecified objects (`city_set` and `max_results_per_city`) and and I get a `DataFrame` with all the entries. I changed some of your code for the salary, as the structure of the website seems to have changed. I did not run any extended tests, though.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
columns = ['city', 'job_title', 'company_name', 'location', 'summary', 'salary']
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
city_set = ('Toronto, ON', 'Calgary, AB', 'Montréal, QC')
max_results_per_city = 30

#scraping code:
for city in city_set:
    for start in range(0, max_results_per_city, 10):
        page = requests.get('http://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=data+scientist,+data+analyst,+python&l=' + str(city) + '&jt=fulltime')  # + '&start=' + str(start))
        time.sleep(1)  #ensuring at least 1 second between page grabs

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        for div in soup.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'row'}):
    #creating an empty list to hold the data for each posting
            job_post = []
    #append city name
            job_post.append(city)
    #grabbing job title
            for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
                job_post.append(a['title']) 
    #grabbing company name
                company = div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'company'}) 
                if len(company) > 0:
                    [job_post.append(b.text.strip()) for b in company]
                else:
                    [job_post.append(span.text) for span in div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'result-link-source'})]
    #grabbing location name
                [job_post.append(span.text) for span in div.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'location'})]
    #grabbing summary text
                [job_post.append(span.text.strip()) for span in div.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'summary'})]
    #grabbing salary
                div_two = div.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'salarySnippet'})
                job_post.append(div_two.text.strip() if div_two else 'Nothing found')
    #appending list of job post info to dataframe at index num
                sample_df.loc[len(sample_df) + 1] = job_post
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still getting the same error message. I will update my original question to include the full code (with your edits), including dependencies. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, when I comment out the .loc line near the bottom and just try to have it output to .csv, the csv file that gets created is blank, minus the column headers.